# android-amazing-listview onclick event issue in android

Tags: android, onclick, android-listview

I'm using android-amazing-listview in my android application, and I want to show some details when user clicks on an item in listview. But the thing is when I set click listener on the item it also listens the header section as an item. Here is my code below, and you can also take a look to the XML file.

```
    @Override
    public View getAmazingView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View res = convertView;
        if (res == null) res = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);

        TextView lName = (TextView) res.findViewById(R.id.lName);
        TextView lYear = (TextView) res.findViewById(R.id.lYear);

        LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) res.findViewById(R.id.item);

        Items composer = getItem(position);
        lName.setText(composer.title);
        lYear.setText(composer.summary);

        // here I set my click listener just for the item
        item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "OnClick event !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return res;
    }
```

And here is the XML for items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/menu_item" >
<include
    layout="@layout/menu_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/item" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:clickable="true" >
    <TextView 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/lName" />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/lYear" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the reason why the header also is getting clicked when I click the item.

The Reason is I use AmazingListView. So according to this library header and item are the same item of the list. When the header goes to top of the list view, copy of the header is getting drawn to pin it up to head of the list.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution for this? Look like the `getAmazingView` cause wrong position of row item when scrolling.

Comment: It was a long time ago, I don't have a solution as far as I remember.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `setOnClickListener` on each item, you need to use `setOnItemClickListener` on the actual `ListView`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if(view.getTag() != NULL) {
            //deal with click on item at position "position"
        }

    }
});
```

And remove the code where you're attaching listeners to individual items.

**EDIT** Now that I reviewed the AmazingListView documentation a bit more, I realise that you need a bit more to it.  When you're creating the views in `getAmazingView`, set the tag to **1** before returning the view on each item that you want to support the item-click.  When you create subheaders or other non-item-click-enabled elements in the view, set their tag to `null`.  Then check the tag before processing the click (see update in the code above).

Comment: Hey Aleks, I tried many ways to do this including your solution but the issue is not about click events. Click event works quite well, but in the case I scroll down and click the header, header behaves like it's z index is lower than item's z index. So whenever I try to click on it, it clicks the item under the header.

Header is always inactive for click events except when there is no item under the header, when the list is not scrolled down.

Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: you can check what I mean by using this code.
`res.findViewById(R.id.item).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "item !" + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });
   
   res.findViewById(R.id.header).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "header !" + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });`

I tried to click both on item and header here in the code above.

Comment: @osayilgan Have you tried actively catching "click" events on the headers and then discarding them?  I.e. always catch click regardless, but then ignore it if the click was on the header.

Comment: Here I do listen click events only at header. And when I click on the header it directly clicks the item under the header. When there is no item under the header(when the header is at most top of the list) header click works, but when I scroll the list a bit down clicking on the header doesn't response anymore.

`res.findViewById(R.id.header).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { Toast.makeText(context, "header !" + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } });`

Comment: I finally figured out that amazing listview is drawing a canvas for header after user scroll the list down and after header is pinned to top of the list. So that's why we cannot listen click events of header and that's why when I click the header it clicks the item under it. I don't know how but I will try to listen click events of this canvas and then discard it.

Answer (score -1):

Here you add Click listens in Adapter class for item. it take action only for one item( i am not tested). if you want to add click listens in one then it better to add click listeners in list view .

please check  out the [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). here is list view example.

thanks